# How do I merge two datasets with on BusinessID and get the final dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, dataset

It is two datasets **business** and **review** files. how to group the **multiple reviews** on *business_id* to get **all reviews** given by the user into **one text**.

How to **merge** the datasets with **BusinessID** and get the **final dataset** as the picture below?

How can I do this with the **Pandas** library?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `df1` (top-left) with a `.groupby` version of `df2` (top-right):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.groupby('Business_id')['Review_text'].apply(list).reset_index(),
               how='left', on='Business_id').rename({'Review_text':'All_reviews'}, axis=1)

Out[1]: 
   Business_id       category  star  Review_count               All_reviews
0            1       shopping   3.5             3  [Text_1, Text_2, Text_4]
1            2     restaurant   5.0             1          [Text_3, Text_5]
2            3  Home services   4.0             6                       NaN
```